# Is there a way to sort my entire EDMX designer automatically?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx-designer

I have a large amount of tables in entity framework and when I open the EDMX designer I'd like to have some sort of sorting method. Is there a way to do this that doesn't require me to drag and drop every table?

Comment: You should consider split your edmx to small edmx models. You can check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867479/entity-framework-4-does-it-make-sense-to-create-a-single-diagram-for-all-entiti/3868075#3868075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867479/entity-framework-4-does-it-make-sense-to-create-a-single-diagram-for-all-entiti/3868075#3868075)

Comment: @SelimYıldız that's a really good suggestion, thank you.